# WCF project will not be hosted when unit test runs

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I created a WCF project using the IIS model. I then created unit tests which reference services from that project. Now when I start the unit test, the service is not hosted and thus I get EndpointNotFoundExceptions. When I simply hit F5 everything works fine and the IIS Express comes up in tray.

I checked the option "Always start when debugging" in the property-pane of the service-project and it is set to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unit Test is a unit test. If you need another process for it (namely some IIS or other web server) it's no longer a closed unit. If you want to test your service when it's hosted, I'd suggest you host it *in your test* yourself. Check self-hosting services. Then you have control about what class is hosted when and where. For example, you may want a different URL for your unit test and you may want to inject a different data layer so your tests don't need anything outside your unit, like a database.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought, that the debugging-option will start the service in any case. I use DI in this project heavily and I have generic wrappers for using the services. So I wanted to test this behavior with a simple Foo-service. I'll check self-hosting then. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing unit testing, and you are actually doing integration testing, since your test suit has no direct knowledge/binding of the service codes and it is just a client program of the service.

Both unit testing and integration testing contribute to good QA. Generally you should create unit testing which directly test the service codes through in process binding interfaces, and make sure it has comprehensive code coverage.

Then create integration testing using MS Test, NUnit or xUnit as test harness, in order to test some run time behaviors of the service.

What puzzle you is that how to make the test suit in the same VS sln run while the service should be running in debug mode. There could be a few solutions:

1. Build the test suit using Nunit or xUnit, then run the test suit outside VS IDE which is running the service in Debug mode. Actually MS Test could support as well, but only in command line mode.
2. Host the service in IIS, and you have a batch files to copy assemblies and web.config to there upon every update. Then attach the service codes with respective w3wp.exe instance.
3. If you just want to test rather than debug, there could be another solution: Use IIS Express. You use either C# codes or batch file to launch IIS Express with the service during tearing up, and close IIS Express when tearing down.